# How do I get a while loop that is calculating the factorial to disregard the previous factorials?

Tags: python, while-loop, factorial

**Update**: I have solved the problem of compounding factorials by resetting the factorial to 1 at the start of the loop and eliminating unnecessary code. Here is the new version.

```
more = "yes"
while more == "yes":
    n = int(input("Enter a number to get its factorial: "))
    if n >= 0:
        factorial = 1
        for num in range(1, n+1):
            factorial *= num
        print(n,'!=', factorial)
        more = input("Would you like to get another number's factorial?:")
    else:
        print("Factorials are not defined for negative integers.")
print("Thank You!")
```

Comment: update: I have fixed the issue and simplified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the factorial variable to 1 at the start of the while loop.

Also, you'll want to check if n is positive for every input, as it currently only does so for the first.

Comment: Thanks Dima! I solved the compounding issue but now I am running into a problem where it is displaying the negative integers inputted as being equal to a factorial of one and then asking for another integer. Here is what I have...

Comment: The code can be a lot simpler which would help you figure out the problem. For starters, put everything inside the while loop and only have the code that asks for a number once in the code, at the start of the loop.

Comment: I solved the problem thanks so much Dima! You da best!